# Loading a node_module from above the current directory

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm building an app with multiple sub-apps. The file structure is like this:

```
├── app1
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── node_modules
│   └── package.json
├── shared
│   └── foo.js
```

In `app.js`, I'm loading `foo.js` like this:

```
require('../shared/foo');
```

And in `foo.js` I try to use an `npm` module, `body-parser`, like this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

This thorws a "cannot find module error" – `body-parser` is installed in the `app1/node_modules` directory, but `foo.js` is obviously looking in its own directory and not finding it.

Is there a way to tell a `require()` call to use the working directory of the file it's called from rather than its own directory? Or do I need to have a second `package.json` inside `/shared` to allow for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an approach found via [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520):

In `foo.js` I changed my `require()` calls to look like this:

```
var bodyParser = require(__base + 'body-parser');
```

And in `app.js` (which loads `foo.js`), I added this to the top:

```
global.__base = __dirname + '/node_modules/';
```

It's not beautiful, but it works.